# Opening .inl file breaks IntelliSense globally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017, latest version (just updated yesterday).

I'm using DirectXMath which uses `.inl` files for some things. I understand why IntelliSense has problems with `.inl` files, however in my case, Visual Studio breaks IntelliSense for my files.

A simple snipped of code on which I can reproduce the problem:

```
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DirectXCollision.h>

void f() {
    DirectX::XMMATRIX projLH;
    DirectX::XMMATRIX viewLH;
    DirectX::BoundingFrustum fr{ projLH };
    fr.Transform(fr, DirectX::XMMatrixInverse(nullptr, viewLH));
}
```

All works fine, VS knows about all types and functions. When I now right-click on a type or function and click `Show Definition`, Visual Studio shows me the source code in a overlay, which might be in a header file or in a `.inl` file. *Sometimes* (after three or four times), after I close this overlay, Visual Studio forgets about all the types. `XMMATRIX`, `projLH`, `viewLH`, `fr` and `XMMatrixInverse` all have red squiggly lines underneath and hovering the words says `namespace DirectX has no member 'XMMATRIX'` , `; expected` and so on. *It still compiles though*.

This is quite annoying as I have to restart Visual Studio each time to fix this. Closing and reopening the file doesn't help. The next time I want to look at a declaration and the declaration happens to be in a `.inl` file, it breaks again. *Why* does IntelliSense break for *my* code once I opened a `.inl` file? Can I somehow globally disable IntelliSense for `.inl` files or how would I prevent this problem?

Comment: Hi tkausl, as far as I know, we can't configure Visual Studio to let intellisense skip a file, if you right click the solution name and clean the solution, does this issue persists or not?

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Cleaning or rebuilding the project or solution doesn't help. Reloading the project ("Rescan Solution") works, but I don't really want to reload the project each time as it takes a few seconds and I'm looking at definitions quite a lot, which means I'd have to reload really regularly.